# Samsung Tizen.Net Wearable, How to control object font size dynamically

Tags: xamarin.forms, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

When using objects which contain text, such as a button or label, how can the text be dynamically sized in order to better keep text of different lengths within the viewable area?

For example if a `Label` within a `Cell` of a `CircleListView` of a `CirclePage` and the text becomes too long, it will easily fall out of view:

[image]

For context to what im looking for, in Android I am able to give an object either an `autoSizeMinTextSize` and/or `autoSizeMaxTextSize` tags which will automatically resize the font size based on the text length of the object.
This allows text of unknown lengths to be better kept on the screen.

[image]

How can this be done with in a Tizen.Net application, using `CircularUI` elements like `Button` or `Label` or with Xamarin.Forms in general?

Comment: After you add some code, someone will let you know the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into this for a while I was able to learn of a few ways to resize text dynamically.

Take a center aligned `Label`:

```
PrimaryText = new Label
{
    FontSize = _maxFontSize,
    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
};
```

Adding it to a Layout gives it access to the `MeasureInvalidated` event:

```
TextStack = new StackLayout
{
    WidthRequest = _maxWidth,
    Children = { PrimaryText }
};
```

Then when the text changes (among other things) the event will trigger where you can measuer the new text, compare it to the width of the stack, and then manipulate the size of font until the text fits within your layout:

```
TextStack.MeasureInvalidated += (sender, args) =>
{
    var primaryMeasure = PrimaryText.Measure(PrimaryText.Width, PrimaryText.Height);
    var stackMeasure = TextStack.Measure(TextStack.Width, TextStack.Height);

    if (primaryMeasure.Request.Width > stackMeasure.Request.Width)
    {
        if (PrimaryText.FontSize <= _minFontSize)
            PrimaryText.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start;
        else
        {
            var fontSize = PrimaryText.FontSize - 2;
            if (fontSize < _minFontSize)
                fontSize = _minFontSize;

            PrimaryText.FontSize = fontSize;
        }
    }
};
```